# AngularJS: global access to function defined in a controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope, window

I have an angularjs app with some controllers.

At some point, I need to access a function defined inside a controller, but the place where the function is gonna be called is not inside the angularjs APP.

I'll try to build a simple scenario:

```
app.controller('TaskController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $window, TaskEngine, PortalUtil) {

$scope.closeTask = function() {
    $scope.openTask = false;
    $scope.openedTaskUrl = undefined;
}

});
```

-- Some other place in my web app, outside of the angular APP.

```
<button onclick="closeTask();">
```

The "closeTask()" function is never accessible, because its out of scope.
I tried to define it in the window object

```
$window.closeTask = function() {
    $scope.openTask = false;
    $scope.openedTaskUrl = undefined;
}

});
```

Now, my function is visible, but the variables "openTask" and "openedTaskUrl" are not.
Is it possible to do what I want?
Basically, I have a controller, and I need to access one function anywhere, to control the behaviour of a menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use $window for this. Instead, Angular has a nice feature which lets not Angular code to interact with it. Using [Angular.element](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/angular.element) you can access data or functions defined in Angulars Scope.

```
 var $scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app=app]')).scope();
 $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.print("Hello world"); 
 });
```